# Why is there no sound in SSFIV:AE on the PC?

Tags: pc, super-street-fighter-iv

I have SSFIVAE2012 for PC and when I play there is no sound.

When I start the game there is sound for the ads and the intro movie, but once I am in the menu the game is completely silent, except for the Windows Live commands. If someone comes online I get an acoustic beep signal. So the audio still works, but neither game music nor sound effects are played.

I checked the volume in the settings and everything seems to be configured correctly.

The game was copied from from my laptop as I cannot find my original DVD. But I can login and play online. The issue is there is absolutely no sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my original DVD, deleted the "Super Street Fighter IV" directory and installed everything again.

Now the sound works as expected.